# How to manage the varying behaviour of SVGs for different pins. I want to hide the SVG itself while keeping its copied element visible

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have the big svg displayed on the react.js app. I have duplicated the part of that big svg and display in the other place.

here is how I have duplicated it:

```
         <use
          className="svg__visual__preview"
          xlinkHref={`#${pinId}`}
          style={{
            height: "1%",
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            "--opacity-description": 0,
            "--pin-opacity": 1,
            "--visibility-halo": "hidden",
            "--map-display":"block !important",
            // aspectRatio: "16/9",

            "--map-scale": markerScale,

            //
          }}
        />
```

The problem I am having is with "--map-display":"block !important", this is the dynamic part that will be hide on click of button. If I keep make the original svg display none then it will hide the duplicated svg also. I cannot make the different svg and use them separetely because user can perform cetrain tasks on that svg so it may change shape or color thats why i have to duplicate it. but for some condition i want to hide the svg on original map but display it at other place. I have tried applying --map-display to the parent of this  tab but still not worked. can anyone help please.

Please help me figure out this problem. How i can display the duplicated svg while hiding the original one.

Comment: Create multiple <use> then you don't need to hide the original, you can hide a copy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the different approach. rather than hiding it. i have moved it to outside of dom and not it will not display in SVG but still i can access it and displays the duplicate svg:

here is what I did, may be useful for someone else:

```
const svg = document.getElementById("your-svg-id");

if (!mapPinVisibility) {
  // Create a hidden container element
  const hiddenContainer = document.createElement("div");
  hiddenContainer.style.position = "absolute";
  hiddenContainer.style.top = "-9999px"; // Move the container outside the visible area

  // Detach the SVG element from its parent and append it to the hidden container
  const parent = svg.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(svg);
  hiddenContainer.appendChild(svg);

  // Append the hidden container to the document body
  document.body.appendChild(hiddenContainer);
} else {
  // If mapPinVisibility is true, move the SVG element back to its original parent
  const hiddenContainer = document.querySelector("div[style='position: absolute; top: -9999px;']");
  if (hiddenContainer) {
    const parent = hiddenContainer.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(hiddenContainer);
    parent.appendChild(svg);
  }
}
```